# Determine if a socket can be read or used

Tags: python, sockets

Is there a way to determine if a socket can still be read? I tried isinstance and type but their type are the same as each other even if one has been closed and another is active so I'm trying to figure out how to see if a socket is alive and can be read or used or can not be so I can avoid this error: `OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket`

Comment: Can you post your code?  The error is pretty black and white, you're, most likely, trying to do a "select" on something that problem is not a socket...

Comment: @mastashake57 the problem is where I'm connecting to the socket, I close the socket connection when I'm done with it but I have a while loop on it and it trys to read the closed socket so I'm trying to figure out how to use an if statement or something to do `if condition: return` to avoid the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, ruler, I think I know what you're getting at.

What you want to do is break out of your while loop once your data stream reaches the end THEN close the socket after you're said and done.  In the past, I have done the folowing:

```
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    conn.send(data)
conn.close()
```

The while loop will remain so long as data streams in (based on the if loop).  Otherwise, it will break out of the loop and, finally, close the socket.  This way, you won't even have to worry about your socket closing on your mid-loop... just check for your stream and close it once all the data has been received.  Hopefully, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, you can do this by running the [netstat](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/netstat.mspx?mfr=true) command using the python [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) and then parsing the output.

```
import subprocess
output, error = subprocess.Popen(['netstat','-n'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()

# then parse the port numbers / states out of the variable *output*
```